# Rails conditional validation: if: doesn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm new to rails, I have a trip class with three foreign key. Two of these associate it with the same class: Place.

This is my model:

```
class Trip < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :from, class_name: "Place", foreign_key: "from_id"
    belongs_to :to, class_name: "Place", foreign_key: "to_id"
    belongs_to :vehicle, class_name: "Vehicle", foreign_key: "vehicle_id"

    validates :price, presence: true
    validates :time, presence: true
    validates :from_id, presence: true
    validates :to_id, presence: true, if: :from_different_to?
    
    def from_different_to?
        to_id != from_id
    end
end
```

All model tests pass except for the last one:

```
class TripTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @place1 = Place.create(name:"NewYork",cap:"11111",lat:"1234",long:"1478")
    @place2 = Place.create(name:"Los Angeles", cap:"22222", lat:"1234",long:"1478")
    @vehicle = Vehicle.create(targa: "ab123cd",modello:"500",marca:"Fiat", posti:5,alimentazione:"benzina")
    @trip = Trip.new(price: 10, time: Time.new(2021, 10, 14, 12,03), from_id: @place1.id, to_id: @place2.id,vehicle_id: @vehicle.id)  
  end
...

test "Departure id and arrival id should be different" do
    @trip.to_id = @place1.id
    assert_not @trip.valid?
  end
```

that result in a failure:

```
Failure:
TripTest#test_Departure_id_and_arrival_id_should_be_different [/media/alessandro/DATA/Universita/Magistrale/1_anno/Programmazione_concorrente/hitchhiker/test/models/trip_test.rb:45]:
Expected true to be nil or false
```

I'm not able to understand why.
Can someone help me?

Comment: @spickermann the record IS valid, but they expect it not to be. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @spickermann in setup I set `to_id: @place2.id`, but in the test I set `@trip.to_id = place1.id`, so `to_id == from_id == @place1.id`. This because I want an invalid trip to try if effectively the model reject this record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you think `validates ... if:` works differently as it actually does. This line

```
validates :to_id, presence: true, if: :from_different_to?
```

translates to validate that the `to_id` is present if the `from_different_to` method returns `true`. When `from_different_to` evaluates to `false` then do not validate. See [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless).

That means when you define

```
@trip.to_id = @place1.id
assert_not @trip.valid?
```

in your test then the first line disables the check for the presence of the `to_id`. No validation, no error...

I suppose what you really try to achieve is to validate that to `to_id` is present *and* `from_id` and `to_id` are not equal. This can be done with a [custom validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) like this:

```
validates :to_id, presence: true
validate :validates_places_are_different

private
def validates_places_are_different
  errors.add(:to_id, "must be different to from_id") if to_id == from_id
end
```

Comment: Yes, you've hit the problem. I misunderstood how `if:` works. Thank you for the answer, I solved my problem, unfortunately I don't have the needed reputation to give you a +1, but your help was invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not able to understand why. Can someone help me?

That `if` conditionally enables a validation. Your `to_id` is the same as `from_id` and so `to_id` is not validated at all. But even if it was, `to_id` has a value, so there wouldn't be an error from this field.

---

Overall, I'm not quite sure why are you expecting a validation error here or what that error should be. In my experience, assertions like `assert_not @model.valid?` are virtually useless. The record might not be valid because of unrelated reasons and you'll have no idea. Personally, I assert the exact error message I'm expecting. Something along these lines (rspec syntax)

```rb
it "requires first_name" do
  expected_messages = {
    first_name: [:blank],
  }

  @model.valid?
  expect(@model.errors.full_messages).to eq expected_messages
end
```

Comment: The concept is: from_id and to_id are equal, so if `@trip.valid?` return false, means that my model (Trip) has rejected the record (how it should do), `assert_not false` => the test is passed. The problem is that my model doesn't reject the record, so my question is why this happens?

Comment: @AleCrout  Yes, I understand how `assert_not @trip.valid?` works. My question was, I don't understand why you expected the model to be valid. But it looks like spickermann gave you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to that of @spickermann is that:

```
class Trip < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :from, class_name: "Place", foreign_key: "from_id"
    belongs_to :to, class_name: "Place", foreign_key: "to_id"
    belongs_to :vehicle, class_name: "Vehicle", foreign_key: "vehicle_id"

    validates :price, presence: true
    validates :time, presence: true
    validates :from_id, presence: true
    validates :to_id, numericality: {other_than: :from_id}, if: :from_place_id?

    def from_place_id
        from_id
    end

    def from_place_id?
        !from_id.nil?
    end
end
```

Note that we have to put a control to execute the last validates only if from_id is not null, because if we doesn't do that, we vanificate the control `validates :from_id, presence:true` on the superior line.